# I encountered a Runtime Error while trying to finetune a LILT (LayoutLM) model

Tags: pytorch, nlp, gpu, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to finetune a LILT model.
I prepared data represented as

```
{
'input_ids': [],
'attention_mask': [],
'bbox': [],
'labels': []
}
```

the value of each key in the above dictionary is of length 512 to match the model input.
I start the training just after preparing the dataloader represented as

```
input_ids torch.Size([4, 512])
attention_mask torch.Size([4, 512])
bbox torch.Size([4, 512, 4])
labels torch.Size([4, 512])
```

and i obtained the following error

```
----> 3 trainer.train()

17 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/trainer.py in train(self, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval, **kwargs)
   1660             self._inner_training_loop, self._train_batch_size, args.auto_find_batch_size
   1661         )
-> 1662         return inner_training_loop(
   1663             args=args,
   1664             resume_from_checkpoint=resume_from_checkpoint,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/trainer.py in _inner_training_loop(self, batch_size, args, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval)
   1927                         tr_loss_step = self.training_step(model, inputs)
   1928                 else:
-> 1929                     tr_loss_step = self.training_step(model, inputs)
   1930 
   1931                 if (

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/trainer.py in training_step(self, model, inputs)
   2697 
   2698         with self.compute_loss_context_manager():
-> 2699             loss = self.compute_loss(model, inputs)
   2700 
   2701         if self.args.n_gpu > 1:

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/trainer.py in compute_loss(self, model, inputs, return_outputs)
   2729         else:
   2730             labels = None
-> 2731         outputs = model(**inputs)
   2732         # Save past state if it exists
   2733         # TODO: this needs to be fixed and made cleaner later.

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1499                 or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501             return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/models/lilt/modeling_lilt.py in forward(self, input_ids, bbox, attention_mask, token_type_ids, position_ids, head_mask, inputs_embeds, labels, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
   1027         return_dict = return_dict if return_dict is not None else self.config.use_return_dict
   1028 
-> 1029         outputs = self.lilt(
   1030             input_ids,
   1031             bbox=bbox,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1499                 or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501             return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/models/lilt/modeling_lilt.py in forward(self, input_ids, bbox, attention_mask, token_type_ids, position_ids, head_mask, inputs_embeds, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
    817         layout_embedding_output = self.layout_embeddings(bbox=bbox, position_ids=position_ids)
    818 
--> 819         encoder_outputs = self.encoder(
    820             embedding_output,
    821             layout_embedding_output,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1499                 or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501             return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/models/lilt/modeling_lilt.py in forward(self, hidden_states, layout_inputs, attention_mask, head_mask, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
    528                 )
    529             else:
--> 530                 layer_outputs = layer_module(
    531                     hidden_states,
    532                     layout_inputs,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1499                 or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501             return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/models/lilt/modeling_lilt.py in forward(self, hidden_states, layout_inputs, attention_mask, head_mask, output_attentions)
    451         output_attentions: Optional[bool] = False,
    452     ) -> Tuple[torch.Tensor]:
--> 453         self_attention_outputs = self.attention(
    454             hidden_states,
    455             layout_inputs,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1499                 or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501             return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/models/lilt/modeling_lilt.py in forward(self, hidden_states, layout_inputs, attention_mask, head_mask, output_attentions)
    381         output_attentions: Optional[bool] = False,
    382     ) -> Tuple[torch.Tensor]:
--> 383         self_outputs = self.self(
    384             hidden_states,
    385             layout_inputs,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1499                 or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501             return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/models/lilt/modeling_lilt.py in forward(self, hidden_states, layout_inputs, attention_mask, head_mask, output_attentions)
    247 
    248         key_layer = self.transpose_for_scores(self.key(hidden_states))
--> 249         value_layer = self.transpose_for_scores(self.value(hidden_states))
    250         query_layer = self.transpose_for_scores(mixed_query_layer)
    251 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1499                 or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501             return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py in forward(self, input)
    112 
    113     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 114         return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
    115 
    116     def extra_repr(self) -> str:

RuntimeError: CUDA error: CUBLAS_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED when calling cublasLtMatmul with transpose_mat1 1 transpose_mat2 0 m 768 n 2048 k 768 mat1_ld 768 mat2_ld 768 result_ld 768 abcType 0 computeType 68 scaleType 0
```

Can anyone help to solve this problem ? I searched in Google however I didn't find a solution
thank you in advance

i tried to verify that all the inputs have the same dimensions
I run the script on cpu to get a more explicit error and I get the following error

```
    161     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 162         return F.embedding(
    163             input, self.weight, self.padding_idx, self.max_norm,
    164             self.norm_type, self.scale_grad_by_freq, self.sparse)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in embedding(input, weight, padding_idx, max_norm, norm_type, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
   2208         # remove once script supports set_grad_enabled
   2209         _no_grad_embedding_renorm_(weight, input, max_norm, norm_type)
-> 2210     return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)

IndexError: index out of range in self
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

The problem occurred when executing the forward function belonging to the `LiltLayoutEmbeddings(nn.Module)` class, which requires the creation of w_position_embeddings that are equal to `w_position_embeddings(bbox[ :, :, 2] - bbox[ :, :, 0])`.
Checking the bboxes created during batch preparation, I found that for some of the data used for training and evaluation, the indices were outside the embeddings dictionary. As a result, embedding fails.
As the problem concerns few samples, I simply deleted them to overcome this issue.